How to pass Subranges in VBA
I am writing a VBA function that ensures a row is considered "Valid" if all the cells in the row are populated with values. Below is my code:
Public Function validEntry(rng As Range) As Boolean

    Dim cell As Range
    
    ' Assume the range is valid unless proven otherwise
    validEntry = True
    
    ' Loop through each cell in the range
    For Each cell In rng
        ' Check if the cells belongs to a merged area
        If cell.MergeCells Then
            ' Only check the value in the top-left cell of the merged area
            If IsEmpty(cell.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Value) Then
                validEntry = False
                Exit Function ' Exit if any merged area is empty
            End If
        Else
            ' Check individual cell if it is not part of a merged area
            If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
                validEntry = False
                Exit Function ' Exit if any non-merged cell is empty
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

End Function

Now, I am trying to create another function that takes a 2D range, loops through each row, and returns whether each row is valid or not.
Here is an example of the code:
Function Test(rng As Range) As Variant
    
    Dim Results() As Variant
    
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ReDim Results(1 To rng.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
    
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        Results(i, 1) = validEntry(rng.Rows(i))
    Next i
    
    Test = Results

End Function

This function only returns 'True' if the row is valid or not. I can't find any documentation on how 'rng.Rows()' works, and I would appreciate any tips or clarification.

Are you calling Test from a worksheet cell? If Yes, exactly how are you doing that?  rng.Rows is a collection of all rows in rng, similar to worksheet.rows property.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.rows

You could use something like that (with your own adjustments to suit your actual inputs):
Function CheckRowsValidity(rng As Range) As Collection
    Dim row As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim results As New Collection
    Dim isValid As Boolean
    Dim rowNumber As Long
    
    For Each row In rng.Rows
        isValid = True
        rowNumber = row.row
        
        For Each cell In row.Cells
            If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
                isValid = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cell
        
        If isValid Then
            results.Add "Row " & rowNumber & ": Valid"
        Else
            results.Add "Row " & rowNumber & ": Invalid"
        End If
    Next row

    Set CheckRowsValidity = results
End Function

Sub TestCheckRowsValidity()
    Dim result As Collection
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim checkRange As Range
    
    ' Define the range to check (adjust as needed)
    Set checkRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C5")
    
    Set result = CheckRowsValidity(checkRange)
    
    ' Output the results in the Immediate Window (Ctrl + G to view)
    For Each item In result
        Debug.Print item
    Next item
End Sub



Check If Range Is Populated feat. ('Evil') Merged Cells

Results
Small:        True
Small:        True,True,True
Big:          False
Big:          True,True,True,True,True,True,False,False,False,True

The Method (Example)
Sub TestValidity()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, bData() As Boolean

    ' Scenario 1 (Small):
    
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A2:C4")
    
    Debug.Print "Small:", IsValidEntry(rng)
    
    bData = GetRangeRowsValidity(rng)
    ' Join to show in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).
    Debug.Print "Small:", Join(Application.Transpose(bData), ",")
    ' Write to the right of the range leaving one empty column.
    'rng.Columns(1).Offset(, rng.Columns.Count + 1).Value = bData
    
    ' Scenario 2 (Big):
    
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A2:C11")
    
    Debug.Print "Big:", IsValidEntry(rng)
    
    bData = GetRangeRowsValidity(rng)
    ' Join to show in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).
    Debug.Print "Big:", Join(Application.Transpose(bData), ",")
    ' Write to the right of the range leaving two empty columns.
    'rng.Columns(1).Offset(, rng.Columns.Count + 2).Value = bData
    
End Sub

The Functions
Function GetRangeRowsValidity(ByVal rng As Range) As Boolean()
    
    Dim bData() As Boolean: ReDim bData(1 To rng.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim r As Long, rrng As Range
    
    For Each rrng In rng.Rows
        r = r + 1
        bData(r, 1) = IsValidEntry(rrng)
    Next rrng
    
    GetRangeRowsValidity = bData

End Function

Function IsValidEntry(ByVal rng As Range) As Boolean
    
    Dim RowsCount As Long: RowsCount = rng.Rows.Count
    Dim ColsCount As Long: ColsCount = rng.Columns.Count
    
    Dim Data() As Variant:
    If RowsCount + ColsCount = 2 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
    Else
        Data = rng.Value
    End If
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        For c = 1 To ColsCount
            If IsEmpty(Data(r, c)) Then
                With rng.Cells(r, c)
                    If .MergeCells Then ' is merged
                        If IsEmpty(.MergeArea(1).Value) Then Exit Function
                    Else ' is not merged
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
            
    IsValidEntry = True

End Function

